# How to fix CORS issue When call Instagram Rapid API

Tags: api, instagram-api, php-curl, rapidapi

I want to show Instagram photos by [Instagram API](https://rapidapi.com/neotank/api/instagram130) with the PHP-curl method which provides by Rapid API. I can retrieve all data but I can't show images because CORS issue.

show an error message in the console and didn't img.

```
GET https://instagram.flba2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/328544713_963151857909010_5604593002897101398_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s1080x1080&_nc_ht=instagram.flba2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=110&_nc_ohc=NgdRemmUwKcAX-bXw5O&edm=AOQ1c0wBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfC1Aczgi9v9OSPIxKibauK-pVpOMlF3KTHCECKLMyKKWg&oe=63E735EE&_nc_sid=8fd12b net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin 200
```

Screenshot URL: https://ibb.co/xJPK39B

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a CORs policy issue, it means something is blocking your request because its from a different origin or domain

A few things you can try:

- sometimes API keys take a while to become valid so wait a bit & restart the server
- verify server permissions (check directory permissions)
- verify the software is upto date to handle the requests

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).